# Как установить HeidiSQL на Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Добрый день.

Подскажите, как установить `heidisql` на Ubuntu? Желательно без `wine`.

Comment: Ответ дан на другом ресурсе StackExchange ссылка на ответ [ответ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153687/how-to-download-install-heidisql-on-linux)